# vb.net / excel dna optional boolean parameter

Tags: vb.net, function, declaration, optional-parameters

I am using vb.net 2015 and Excel DNA to write an Excel UDF *.xll file. The function has one Boolean optional parameter, which sets to "False" if the user does not set any value, but I would like to default it to "True".

Looking for missing input or any such solutions does not work as when I am debugging the function and stop it at the line shown below the variable `IgnoreEmptyTrue` is set to "False". It is still "False" after stopping at the next line.

```
Public Function vbCountUniqueValues(ByVal DataRange As Object, Optional ByVal IgnoreEmptyTrue As Boolean = True) As Integer

 Dim varArrayOutput As New ArrayList
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: When you call function, just pass "True" for the parameter in question without relying on the default value.

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration#step-by-step-for-visual-basic
It sounds like only apply to VB but I don't know if it is up-to-date